# Redmine and ckeditor uploadimage plugin

Tags: plugins, ckeditor, redmine

On Redmine 3.4.3 with CK editor plugin we can't make this uploadimage ckeditor plugin work.

Where should we put the uploadimage folder ?  in the \plugins\redmine_ckeditor\assets\ckeditor-contrib\plugins folder ? but when I do so (and restart apache) the ckeditor icons are all gone !

According to https://github.com/a-ono/redmine_ckeditor/issues/216 it may be even much more complex than that!

Can you please check what I did wrong:

1- download the uploadimage ckeditor plugin from https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/uploadimage (there is only one file plugin.js in this plugin!!)

2- uncompress the uploadimage folder in the \plugins\redmine_ckeditor\assets\ckeditor-contrib\plugins folder

3- restart apache

Missing something ? And which config.js file should I edit ? What should I write there ? Should I have CKFinder already installed ?

thanks

cyril

Comment: I don't remember needing that plugin... You are trying to paste images from clipboard or?

Comment: Yes, CKeditor alone won't accept to paste an image from the clipboard. you have to upload an image file.

Answer (score 1):

i did your test on my Debian Stretch Linux and got the same error.

However the apache error file shows:

```
age/Cor/App/Implementation.cpp:304 ]: Could not spawn process for application /usr/share/redmine: An error occurred while starting up the preloader.
  Error ID: 778fb98c
  Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-wXVYHK.html
  Message from application: Could not create directory /usr/share/redmine/instances/default/public/plugin_assets/redmine_ckeditor/ckeditor-contrib/plugins/uploadimage: Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /usr/share/redmine/instances/default/public/plugin_assets/redmine_ckeditor/ckeditor-contrib/plugins/uploadimage (RuntimeError)
```

Then after giving the correct permission via the command below, the plugin works fine:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /usr/share/redmine/instances/default/public/plugin_assets/*
```

Comment: You may want to edit your code to format commands better, as it stands your answer is good but not the easiest to read